# generated executable of Net-Snmp is not getting distributed

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmptrapd

Actually I compiled a source file of Net-Snmp-5.7.1 version on windows system by using Visual Studio C++ (2008).Its working fine on that particular machine,but whenever I tried to take this compiled source & make it run on another windows system,Its given this error `THE SYSTEM CANNOT EXECUTE THE SPECIFIED PROGRAM`. Even though I am using Microsoft redistributed package on the target machine..Anyone who can help me on  this,please help.I am looking desperately for your help.
ThankYou

Answer (score 0):

`net-snmp` code has a manifest that specifies the version(s) and operating system. There are many conditional compilation code in source-code of  net-snmp. **Although this is not specific to net-snmp. Some DLLs cannot be found at another window machine that the reason for** “ The system cannot executed the specified program”.[**READ HERE**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikolad/archive/2005/06/09/427101.aspx)

Comment: Hi Grijesh , really thankful & appreciate your fast answer.But I am using the same Windows-XP service pack3.Any Idea,Why still it is not able to run on the same Windows-Xp

Comment: @Gaurav But machine is different na?..I don't know how to verify windows DLL...Net-SNMP do many system call, Try different(all) commands I guess some should work e.g snmp-translate.

Comment: Ok....Here I want to add,that if I installed Microsoft Visual C++ on target machine, its starts working..any Idea???????

Comment: @Gaurav Very good! ... I guess when you install `Microsoft Visual C++ on target machine` it add some missing packages in OS. to Net-SNMP start-working.

Comment: Yes...It means I have to install Microsoft Visual C++ on every machine???Its really hectic & will take lot of drive space..I want to avoid it completely by using redistributable,but its not working!!

Comment: @Gaurav : you can mail this issue to the email I given to you.

Comment: @Gaurav : useful http://www.linkedin.com/groups?gid=873317&sharedKey=&goback=%2Eanb_1038947_*2_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1